# Pairs of Vertices Unreachable from Each Other in a Directed Graph

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-algorithm

I am requested to design an algorithm to determine whether there exists any pair of vertices unreachable from each other in a directed graph. The algorithm must run in *O(|V| + |E|)* time

Meaning: vertex *i* cannot reach vertex *j*, and vertex *j* cannot reach vertex *i*.

I have read about the method for finding strongly connected components, I wonder whether or not I can start from there and devise an algorithm usable under the current circumstance?

Comment: The number of pairs of unreachable nodes might be O(|V|^2), so in the worst-case there's no possible way to list all of the pairs in any time faster than this. Are you sure you need to list all pairs with this property, or just some of the pairs?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I am only requested to determine whether or not such a pair exists... . Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find all strongly connected components in the linear O(V + E) time requested then you are done. This may seem a bit overkill but it solves the problem. To find all strongly connected components, assuming your graph is represented as an adjacency list, perhaps the simplest O(V + E) linear time algorithm is Kosaraju's, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm

Once you find all strongly connected components, then it is fairly simple to test whether there is a pair of strongly connected components that is not connected by any path, by considering the condensed graph where nodes are strongly connected components and an edge exists if there is an edge between any two nodes chosen from the two connected components.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few hints to help you get started:

1. Try solving this problem first when the graph you're given is a DAG. What does the structure of the DAG have to be in order for any pair of nodes to be at least weakly connected?
2. If you compute the strongly-connected components of a graph, those SCCs themselves form a DAG. Could you use this observation, in conjunction with your algorithm for part (1), to form an algorithm that works on arbitrary graphs?

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to find the strongly connected components then you conversely know the vertices that are not connected as well.

The wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm is pretty instructive. I have implemented the algorithm and it is available here. Runs in O (v + E ).  We are assuming that the graph is backed as an adjacency list.

Link for [Kosaraju Implementation in Java](http://khanna111.com/wordPressBlog/2012/04/11/strongly-connected-components-of-a-graph/)

Try it out, hopefully you would find no bugs :-)